# MBProgressHud not hiding after calling hide from another class

Tags: class, mbprogresshud

I have a ViewController called GetInfoViewController. Basically it takes the users input and then sends the input to a NSObject class, ServerConnection. ServerConnection makes a nsurlconnection request and when it is done I want the MBProgressHUD to hide.

GetInfoViewController

```
    - (IBAction)go:(id)sender{

    ServerConnection *serverConnection = [[ServerConnection alloc]init];

    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    HUD.labelText = @"Searching...";

// here the progressHUD shows normally, and the yelpConnectionMethod is successful in retrieving the result.

    [serverConnection yelpConnectionMethod];


}


-(void)endProgressHUD{
    NSLog(@"end called");


    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

ServerConnection.h

I am not going to put all the nsurlconnection code because I don't think it really applies.. but if you want it I can post it

The only line that matters is:
(this is called after all the connections are done.)

```
GetInfoViewController *getinfoVC = [[GetInfoViewController alloc]init];
[getinfoVC endProgressHUD];
```

I call the endProgressHUD method of the getInfoViewController successfully, as it logs "end called". however, the progress hud stays spinning and does not hide.

Any input would be helpful.

Comment: Try this method when showing the HUD - `- (void)showWhileExecuting:(SEL)method onTarget:(id)target withObject:(id)object animated:(BOOL)animated;`. It is a method of MBProgressHUD - selector should be the `yelpConnectionMethod` and target the `serverConnection`, object nil and animated depends on you :)

Comment: And... once again looks like you have saved the day. LOL appreciate the help

Comment: I've posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method when showing the HUD.

`- (void)showWhileExecuting:(SEL)method onTarget:(id)target withObject:(id)object animated:(BOOL)animated;`

It is a method of MBProgressHUD - `selector` should be the `yelpConnectionMethod` and target the `serverConnection`, object = `nil` and animated depends on you :)